# Position fixing to moving movie clip not acting instantly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, position, movieclip

Hi there,

I'm making a game prototype, a “hero” which is controlled by the mouse when clicked. To visualize the player's velocity direction and the direction from hero to mouse, I have made two MovieClip classes: “Direction_mark” and “Direction_pointer”, respectively. They are NOT nested due to issues I've run into when dealing with the possibility.

When trying to make “pushing camera” (where the hero moves and the background is fixed until you reach a certain point near the stage limits and the environment starts to move), though, I had to make the “Directions” movie clips stay in the same position as the hero, even if this moves. So I simply wrote this (the event listener for the function is onEnterFrame):

```
//In the Direction_mark and Direction_pointer class:

//...

function update (e: Event){
    //code...
    this.x = Game.hero.x;
    this.y = Game.hero.y;
    //more code...

}

//...
```

But it doesn't work: I experience a certain “easing”, the “Directions” follow the hero in and elastic-like effect which is not desired at all.

Does somebody know why this happen, and how to solve it? This is the first time I experience this problem. Any help, advice or comment would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

PD: Probably not relevant, but I'm using CDK to manage collisions. Maybe takes too much CPU and makes it work wrong?

Comment: I don't believe this is going to be enough code to go off of, does your "hero" asset have continuous motion? Or does have a force/acceleration model. If the answer is the latter, that might be where the "easing" is coming into play.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yeah, it is the typical acceleration model. There is a gravity which affects y_velocity. Maybe the question is rather stupid and this effect is usual, but I would be shocked because this is the first time I experience it. Does it have an easy solution, or I just have to nest the movie clips (which I want to avoid as much as possible)? Thanks again for the comment.

Comment: This doesn't require and specifics adjustments to parent/child relationships. I'm banking that the easing effect is because you have it tied to the hero's x and y which are tied to it's velocity and acceleration. If you post more code related to this it would be easier to deduce.

Comment: Finally I found a solution: I just took the Direction_pointer class away and made the distance calculation in the Hero_mc itself, and then, to draw the line, I would just use lineTo or other similar functions. Thanks for your help though!